# Find the steady-state part of the complex-valued solution function to: $z'+kz=ke^{it/2}$

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, steady-state

this is a homework question and I don't think I am quite understanding the words my professor has used to form this particular question.

The question states: "Find the steady-state part of the complex-valued solution function to: $z'+kz=ke^{it/2}$. The constant *k* will be part of the function. Now, find the *real* part of this steady state solution.

I attempted the problem from what I know and came up with $z_{complex}=(ke^{it/2})/((i/2)+k)$

From this my real part of the solution is then $(-k^{2}\cos(t/2)-(k/2)\sin(t/2))/(-k^{2}-(1/4))$

Have I interpreted and solved this correctly?

Comment: Steady state means $z'=0$. Hence, the solution is $z=e^{it/2}$

Comment: @J You should learn LaTeX and you could get rid of a pair of minus signs but your approach is mathematically sound and the real part at the end is correct.

Comment: @msm By solution do you mean the complex-valued solution or the steady-state part? I regrettably missed this lecture and I am really lost with this section. If you could just give me some brief intuition as how you came up with that, that would be very much appreciated.

Comment: @msm You think $z(t)=e^{it/2}$ solves this?

Comment: @Did Yes, I am already multitasking that process of learning with my homework now haha, I am very new here, sorry for any naivety in my post

Comment: @msm my professor states that k will be in the function however?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your results seem correct. Cancel the minus sign in the real expression.

Note that the real part is not a solution of the complex equation, but of the real part of it, i.e.,
$$
z'+kz=k\cos(t).
$$

Comment: I upvoted but I'm new so it had no effect. This little bit of info sparked the answer to the next part of this homework assignment so thank you very much for sharing that note!

Comment: I do have one question however, I was under the impression that steady state means that as t approaches infinity, that z approach some constant value? Was @msm correct in that steady state means $z'=0$? Obviously if z is constant this would be true but what constant value does this $z_c$ or even $z_r$ have?

Comment: In context, I would think it refers to constant magnitude, i.e., that there are no exponentially increasing or falling components, or that the solution is bounded on all of $\Bbb R$. $z'=0$ is in contradiction to $z=e^{it/2}$ with $z'=i/2\cdot e^{it/2}$.